# Change system.404 path dynamically based on context

Tags: 8, routes, event-subscribers

I have a site that makes use of the groups module to denote various locations all with their own content.

I'd like to give the ability to programmatically alter the system.404 path depending on the context for each group, to arbitrarily chosen content within the group's content.

I'm not finding a lot of documentation which would point me in the right direction.  Has anyone done this before and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to override DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber::on404. An example would be  CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber::on404, which changes system.404 to the configured custom path. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/275804/how-do-404-pages-work

Comment: Use Context or Rules modules for 404..,